# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column after upgrading to CC 1.7 in custom module

Tags: magento-1.7

I am upgrading a site from 1.6 community to 1.7. A custom module that was working is now breaking with the error:

```
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fulfilled' in 'where clause'";i:1;s:5421:"#0 lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php

app/code/local/FP/Giftcard/Block/Adminhtml/Rewrite/Sales/Order/Grid.php(102): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
```

The queries that are running:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `magento_sales_order_status` AS `main_table`

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `magento_sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE 

(`fulfilled` = '1') GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`
```

The correct queries which are running before the upgrade:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `main_table`.*, MIN(if(magento_sales_flat_order_giftcardproduct.type = 'PHYSICAL', ifnull(fulfilled,0), 0)) AS `fulfilled` FROM `magento_sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `magento_sales_flat_order_giftcardproduct` ON magento_sales_flat_order_giftcardproduct.order_id = main_table.entity_id AND magento_sales_flat_order_giftcardproduct.type = 'PHYSICAL' WHERE (`fulfilled` = '1') GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`) AS `a`

SELECT `main_table`.*, MIN(if(magento_sales_flat_order_giftcardproduct.type = 'PHYSICAL', ifnull(fulfilled,0), 0)) AS `fulfilled` FROM `magento_sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `magento_sales_flat_order_giftcardproduct` ON magento_sales_flat_order_giftcardproduct.order_id = main_table.entity_id AND magento_sales_flat_order_giftcardproduct.type = 'PHYSICAL' WHERE (`fulfilled` = '1') GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id` ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 20
```

The sales order grid rewrite code:

```
Class FP_Giftcard_Block_Adminhtml_Rewrite_Sales_Order_Grid
//    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{
    /**
     * Prepare the order grid columns by adding the totals including the giftcard amount
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        /**
         * @todo
         * Waiting on client specs
         */
        #$this->_addGiftcardColumns();
        $this->_addGiftcardproductColumns();

        $this->sortColumnsByOrder();
        return $this;
    } 

    protected function _addGiftcardColumns()
    {

        $_baseTotal = & $this->getColumn("base_grand_total");
        $_baseTotal["index"] = "base_grand_total_incl_gc";

        $_total = & $this->getColumn("grand_total");
        $_total["index"] = "grand_total_incl_gc";         
    }

    protected function _addGiftcardproductColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumnAfter('giftcard_status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Giftcard Fulfillment Status'),
            'index' => 'fulfilled',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '100px',
            'options' => Mage::helper("fp_giftcard/adminhtml")->getCollectionStatusMap()
        ), 'status');        
    }

    /**
     * Prepare grid collection object
     *
     * @return this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $this->setCollection($collection);        
        if ($this->getCollection()) {

            $this->_preparePage();

            $columnId = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameSort(), $this->_defaultSort);
            $dir      = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameDir(), $this->_defaultDir);
            $filter   = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), null);

            if (is_null($filter)) {
                $filter = $this->_defaultFilter;
            }
            $_pseudo_filter = false;

            if (is_string($filter)) {

                // this line is broken
                $data = $this->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);

                if (isset($data['giftcard_status']) && $data['giftcard_status'] == 0)
                {
                    $alias = $this->getCollection()->getTable("fp_giftcard/sales_giftcardproduct");
                    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("{$alias}.type IS NULL OR {$alias}.type = '" . FP_Giftcard_Helper_Product::GCTYPE_VIRTUAL."'");


                    foreach($data as $k=>$v)
                    {
                        $_pseudo_filter[$k] = $v;
                    }

                    unset($data['giftcard_status']);
                }
                $this->_setFilterValues($data);

            }
            else if ($filter && is_array($filter)) {
                $this->_setFilterValues($filter);
            }
            else if(0 !== sizeof($this->_defaultFilter)) {
                $this->_setFilterValues($this->_defaultFilter);
            }

            if (isset($this->_columns[$columnId]) && $this->_columns[$columnId]->getIndex()) {
                $dir = (strtolower($dir)=='desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
                $this->_columns[$columnId]->setDir($dir);
                $this->_setCollectionOrder($this->_columns[$columnId]);
            }

            if (!$this->_isExport) {
                $this->getCollection()->load();
                $this->_afterLoadCollection();
            }
            if ($_pseudo_filter)
            {
                $this->_setFilterValues($_pseudo_filter);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Wondering if anyone can help me track down what the issue might be and how to fix it?

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but did you try to run the installers again? With n98-magerun it would be `n98-magerun sys:setup:run`. Maybe that helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That didn't fix it.